# Token not evaluating in CiviMail

Tags: civimail, custom-fields, tokens

I have a token for a custom field in my email template, but its not being replaced with the value when the email is sent.

What's wrong?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you implement a custom token?

Answer (score 3):

If you can produce a test for the email, and the token is replaced by the field value, then you might have a permission issue.

It might be buried deeply, but see which role your Cron user has.  Be sure the "CiviCRM - access all custom data" is on for your Cron user.