# Can tokenValue hooks be used in scheduled reminder emails?

Tags: email, tokens, hooks, message-templates

I have the same problem as at http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,32608

I have created a tokenValues hook to fetch the value of a field from a multi-record custom field set.  I have the token hook embedded within a message template.  The hook works fine and correctly populates the value if I trigger it from Actions->Send an email.  But when triggered by a Scheduled Reminder based on x days before end of membership, the value is not filled in within the email that goes out.

I have logging within the token hook which shows that the hook *is* being called and is populating the returned array with the correct value.  I tried to debug further, but I can't figure out from where the tokenValues function is being called.  So I can't figure out why the behavior is different for Action->Send an email vs Scheduled Reminders.

If necessary, I can work around this by running a script to push the value I want into a non multi-record field, as regular custom fields work fine.  But obviously that's a bit of a cludge, and this seems like a bug in CiviCRM.

This is a different issue than that described at  [Token not evaluating in CiviMail](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/token-not-evaluating-in-civimail) - that's discussing custom field permissions, which aren't a problem here.

Comment: I forgot to mention: the tokenValues hook, when called, is passed a $context value of 'CRM_Activity_BAO_Activity'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue of custom tokens not populating for scheduled reminders. The workaround in [Brian Shaughnessy's comment](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-11153?focusedCommentId=83503&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-83503) on [CRM-11153](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-11153) fixed it for me:

> early in tokenValues put:

```
$single = false;
if (!is_array($contactIDs)) {
    $contactIDs = array( $contactIDs );
    $origValues = $values;
    $single = true;
}
```

> then at the very bottom put:

```
if ($single) {
    $values = $origValues + $values[$id];
}
```

`$id` may be something different in your hook implementation.

Other recent comments on that issue suggest that a fix may find its way into CiviCRM core.